# How to wildcard 301 redirect inner blog so all current posts work with new blog name?

Tags: 301-redirect, blog

Say I have the following:

```
http://example.com/blog-domain-name/blog-post.html
```

I want it like this:

```
http://example.com/blog/blog-post.html
```

Can I do this with a simple 301 redirect using wildcard without complex apache mod_rewrite?

Like /blog-domain-name/* /blog/*

Will new blog URL know that I want all requests arriving at destination blog posts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `mod_alias` redirect. If using Apache 2.2.6+ then:

```
Redirect 301 /blog-domain-name /blog
```

Everything after `/blog-domain-name` is appended onto the end of the destination URL, no wildcard is necessary.

On earlier versions of Apache you will need to specify an absolute destination URL:

```
Redirect 301 /blog-domain-name http://example.com/blog
```

> Will new blog URL know that I want all requests arriving at destination blog posts?

Not sure what you mean by this? Isn't the "new blog URL" the "destination blog"? The "new blog URL" won't know whether the request has been redirected or not.

**UPDATE:** From comments, it seems that the actual requirement is to *change* the URL structure. The "new blog name" (ie. the destination URL) does not currently exist and results in a 404. A simple 301 redirect is therefore not appropriate in this instance.

Comment: I mean new 301 /blog/ will know that all requests coming for blog posts located on old /blog-domain-name/ are coming exactly for blog posts and not something else? Will /blog/ know how to properly redirect old blog posts to their new destination?

Comment: Does not work and I get: Bad karma: we can't find that page!

Comment: I think /blog-domain-name/blog-post.html is permanent location and I need to not redirect but change URL. I don't know how to do that in Joomla 1.5

Comment: Yes, it does sound like you need to _change_ the URLs on your site and not redirect after all. Trying to redirect to the new location _that does not exist_ is not going to help you! You could partially solve this with an _internal rewrite_, but you are still going to have to (or rather, "you should") change all the URLs that point to those pages... (although that could perhaps be solved with a redirect, but now it's getting messy) so, yes, you really need to change the URL structure in your CMS (ie. Joomla).

Comment: That's categories you are speaking about? The one that is blog.

Comment: Are you using Joomla/WordPress etc??

Comment: I'm just really referring to the URL. Whether it is the "categories" that determine the URL is specific to your site/CMS. @ECarterYoung Joomla 1.5 is mentioned a few comments up.

Comment: To my Knowledge you cannot use a redirect when a page is created during a Database Query, regardless of CMS.  It's the database that determines the page location, not the directory structure.

Comment: See [this article](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/update-url-paths-joomla-47643.html), as this may or may not help.